# setPointerCapture is cancelled on mobile devices / gestures take over

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

I'm unable to get `setPointerCapture` working on mobile: the capture is always cancelled. I'm testing primarily in Chrome, with remote debug tools.

I call `setPointerCapture` in response to a `pointerMove` event.  I additionally:

- Set `touch-action: none` on all elements in the page
- Call `event.preventDefault` on all pointer events (listening to `pointermove`, `pointerup`, `pointercancel`, `pointerdown`)

When I tap and drag though, the capture is cancelled after a few pixels and the browser's gestures are activated.

**What is the correct way to disable gestures and track pointer movements?**

---

The relevant bits of code look like this.

```
    element.onpointerdown = (ev) => {
        ev.stopPropagation()
        pointer_id = ev.pointerId
        target.setPointerCapture(pointer_id)
        target.addEventListener('pointermove', on_mouse_move)
        target.addEventListener('pointerup', on_mouse_up)
        target.addEventListener('pointercancel', on_pointer_cancel)
    }
```

`target` is another element where I want to capture the mouse movement inside.

Where all the message handlers call `preventDefault` on the event.  Putting a console.log in each one I can see some move's, following by a cancel.

Comment: can you show the code on how you are using `setPointerCapture`?

Comment: @syduki Added the basic code I use.

Comment: what is `target`, `context`? did you tried to set it like this: `ev.target.setPointerCapture(ev.pointer_id)`?

Comment: @syduki Sorry, I removed context, it's just where I stored the pointer_id.  I don't want to capture to `ev.target`, so `target` is a different element.  The `ev.target` is the element being dragged, so mouse movement within that element isn't helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Such desperate measures may finally work after a hard time of debugging, but usually a `touch-action: none` on `body` is enough to disable the touch and make the pointer capture work, if not, then you can do `preventDefault` for `touchstart` event on document with a listener with options `{capture: true, passive: false}`. Anyway, it is not a good practice to put `event.preventDefault` all over the place.

```js
const A = document.getElementById('A');
const B = document.getElementById('B');

const ptrLog = e => console.log(performance.now(), e.target.id, e.type);
const ptrMove = e => {
    ptrLog(e);
    const {x, y, width, height} = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    B.style.transform =
    `translate3d(
        ${e.clientX - x - width/2}px,
        ${e.clientY - y - height * 1.5}px,
    0)`;
};

A.addEventListener('gotpointercapture', e => {
    ptrLog(e);
});

A.addEventListener('lostpointercapture', e => {
    ptrLog(e);
    A.removeEventListener('pointermove', ptrMove);
    A.removeEventListener('pointerup', ptrLog);
    A.removeEventListener('pointercancel', ptrLog);
});

B.addEventListener('pointerdown', e => {
    ptrLog(e);
    A.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
    A.addEventListener('pointermove', ptrMove);
    A.addEventListener('pointerup', ptrLog);
    A.addEventListener('pointercancel', ptrLog);
});

document.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
}, {capture: true, passive: false});
```

```css
body {
    background: black;
    touch-action: none;
}
#A, #B {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    font-size: 3em;
    user-select: none;
}
#A { background: red; }
#B { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div id="A">A</div>
<div id="B">B</div>
```

Comment: I also experimented and found that putting a `touchstart` that cancels events seems to help, at least for Chrome. Something still isn't working on Firefox in my code; I'll have to debug.  Somehow this feels wrong thouhg, but there doesn't appear to be a better solution.

Comment: I have however limited the touchstart event to the element where I capture and also only for the duration of the capture

Answer (score 2):

Apply `style={touch-action: none}` to the element that wants to capture the pointer. This prevents the browser from automatically interpreting touch events as scrolling, or pinch-zoom actions.

You can also selectively prevent the browser from intercepting scroll events with `style={touch-action: pan-x}` (allow sideways scrolling), or `style={touch-action: pan-x}` (allow vertical scrolling).